# Creating a database with map

Tags: php, database, wordpress, mamp

I'm having a lot of trouble work locally for `wordpress` with `mamp`.

When I download `wordpress` and I fill the information about my database they say there is an error.

I have two questions:

- The database information I'm supposed to fill in here is the one provided by my hosting right?
- The information I have to add in the file wp-config-sample is also the database etc provided by my hosting?
- Does the database in my php admin from mamp need to be named the same as the one given by my hosting? In all the tutorials they use a random name.

Comment: You most likely cannot use your hosting database with a local wordpress installation.

Comment: The idea of a local `mamp`, `wamp`, `lamp`, whatever-amp stack is that you have _all_ components locally for development purpose.